# arranging numbers in ascending order

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

Why do i need to declare this for loop for i var for so many times, what is the meaning of this `j` var `(for j=i+1;j<n;j++)` ?

How do I know that number(`i`) >number(`j`). And also `a = number[i];` what is the value of `number[i]` here?

```
#include <stdio.h>


/*
 * C program to accept N numbers and arrange them in an ascending order
 */

    void main() {

    int i, j, a, n, number[30];

    printf("Enter the value of N            \n");
   scanf("%d", &n);
   printf("Enter the numbers \n");

   for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {

    scanf("%d", &number[i]);

  }

   for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {

    for (j = i + 1; j < n; ++j) {

      if (number[i] > number[j]) {

        a = number[i];
        number[i] = number[j];
        number[j] = a;

      }

    }

  }

    printf("The numbers arranged in    ascending order are given below \n");

   for (i = 0; i < n; ++i){

    printf("%d\n", number[i]);

  }

}
```

Comment: Please read : http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: If you had used meaningful var names, you would not be asking us what your own code does:(

Comment: It's 2016, so why are developers still using variable-name type shortcuts from 1950's FORTRAN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite basic program called selection sort.

The wiki article is: [Selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort).

Basically in this program, `i` is first pointing to the first element in the array. Then, `j` points to the next element. If, the element `j` is smaller than element `i`, they get swapped. After swapping, the inner `for` loop still continues, and then `j` points to the next element of what it was pointing to, and again it check if it is smaller, and swaps if it is true.

I think that is being a bit confusing, so I'll now do it with a example.

Let's say we have an array with 3 elements: `4 1 3`. `i` points to the first element that is 4. `j` points to the second element that is 1. It checks if the element `j` is smaller than element `i`.  Yes it is, so it swaps them. Now the array is: `143`. Then `j` moves to the next element. It checks if element `j` is smaller than element `i`. No. Then, the inner loop finishes. Now, `i` is pointing to 4 and `j` is pointing to 3. It check if element `j` is smaller than element `i`. Yes, so it swaps them. So now the array is `134`. well it continues the process till `i` is smaller than 3, or the number of elements of the array. Thus, now, the array got sorted in ascending order.

[image]

This image has been taken from the link mentioned earlier. Red is current min. Yellow is sorted list. Blue is current item.

Well, the line

```
a = number [i];
```

is just copying the value of element `i` of the array `number` to the variable `a`.

The line

```
number [i] = number [j];
```

is just copying the value of element `j` of the number array in its element `i`.

The line

```
number [j] = a;
```

is copying the value of `a` into the element `j` of the array number.

Basically, the lines

```
a = number [i];
number[i] = number [j];
number [j] = a;
```

are swapping the values of `number [i]` and `number [j]`.

Comment: I also don't understand this line of code here ; a=number[i]; number[i]=number[j]; a= number[j]

Comment: Can the downvoter explain?